# Why are Sts. Peter and Linus not on the cool scrollbar-of-the-popes on vatican.va

Tags: catholicism, papacy, clement-of-rome

I was about to add a glib comment in answer to another post in a act totally unbecoming of a stackexchange moderator, when I noticed that the effect would have been completely lost on the OP owing to

https://www.vatican.va/content/vatican/it.html

[image: where are the popes?]

ending with Cletus,  what happened to "Linus, Cletus, Clement"<sub>1</sub>.  I could have sworn I saw Peter and Linus in this list at some point, but it might have been another page on the vatican website.

What possible reason could there be for having a non-standard list of pontifs here?  Do people dispute St. Linus's papacy?  The notion that St. Peter was the first pope isn't a contraversial topic among vatican web developers is it?  Did they run out of numbers? is the vatican website still running on a 16-bit MIPS processor?

<sub>1. I love saying "Linus Cletus Clement"</sub>

Comment: At thebottom of the page you link to is an option to filter by century (secolo). If you select the first century St Peter appears as one would expect.  Also if you filter by name also he appears.  I guess the Papal website developers are not infallible!

Comment: oh man, and if you go back to "filter by century" they're in the list again.  And this is a problem with the English and Italian sites and I hit up the wayback machine and it's been like this for a while.   I'm still holding out that there's a doctrinal reason for this, but this might legitimately just be a bug. So glad I'm not a papal web developer, that'd be a lot of pressure to have your defects interpreted as doctrine.  Probably like the first priest who yawned before proclaiming the Gospel, "What'er ya doin up there Bob?",  "umm, crossing my lips..." TRADITION!

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing as @davidlol.  In addition, once St. Linus and St. Peter appear, the next time you go to the page it will appear initially ! Refreshing the page works too.

Comment: Either they've fixed the bug, or the site works on mobile just fine, because it displayed Peter for me on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like Darcy O'Brien was right after all, there are some hidden popes.  Upon further f-12 inspection, it appears as if St. Linus and St. Peter were somehow excluded from their rightful place within the `<div>` tag of popes.

Clicking on 1st century popes will show them, and they will remain visible when you go back to "filter by century".

I checked the wayback machine for this and it appears to have been a problem for a long time, which makes me wonder where someone can submit a bug report...

[image: Hidden Popes]

Thanks to Grateful Disciples insight, I further inspected the page and noticed that they're not hiddne popes after all, the div tag they're supposed to be in just has its width miscalculated.

`position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 36682px;`

Apparently 36682px is not enough, we need 36947px to hold all those popes! Incidentally, 36947 - 36682 = 265, which is `$number_of_popes-$number_of_antipopes-1` which probably means someone in marketing said "we need padding between these popes" a while back. Which leads me to believe this is an off-by-one error, not a Masonic plot to exclude the first two popes.

Still, it ruins the effect of "hey look at these popes", which is probably a good thing for Catholic Internet humility.

Comment: Looking at how the scrollbar is initialized in `https://www.vatican.va/etc/designs/vatican/library/clientlibs/themes/homepage_popes.min.8bda844745e8f2d23ec58bfffeefa173.js` the web developer seems to use this [lazy load library](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload).  Either it's not configured properly or there's a bug in the library.  This explains that once St. Linus and St. Peter are loaded, it stays there because the DOM elements have been added to the div with id=pope-scrollbar.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple ha, you're right, I think I figured it out, guessing nobody programming a lazyloader thinks that hard about horizontal scrolling of 265 elements. I'm just glad it the problem wasn't that they couldn't calculate signed int's greater than 16 bits.  I was a little worried when I saw the width stuck in the 30,000's.

Comment: Javascript native Number type [is 64 bit floating point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) enough to represent 17 digit integer, so we're safe there for many more popes to come.  Anyway, with this answer C.SE is now officially in the business of troubleshooting doctrinal implications of Christian website bugs :-).  I would love to debug this further, but I got work to do.